# AppWrite unable to query by date with dart

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, appwrite

I'm dealing with some problems while querying a database hosted on AppWrite in dart. Basically I need to query a date that is save in AppWrite.

```
final response = await _db.listDocuments(
   databaseId: AppwriteConstants.database_id,
   collectionId: AppwriteConstants.collection_id_events,
   queries: [
      Query.equal('fk_user', fk_user),
      Query.equal('​​date', date.toIso8601String()),
   ],
);
```

Without the second query `Query.equal('date', date.toIso8601String())` the call is fine since it returns all the documents with `fk_user = user` and in this case the date is returned with the format: `2023-12-15T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

While creating a document the date is added in this way:

```
final response = _db.createDocument(
   databaseId: AppwriteConstants.database_id,
   collectionId: AppwriteConstants.collection_id_events,
   documentId: ..,
   data: {
      ...
      'date': date.toIso8601String(),
      'startTime': startTime.toIso8601String(),
      'endTime': endTime.toIso8601String(),
      ...
   },
);
```

If I print the `date.toIso8601String()` it returns: `2023-12-15T00:00:00.000` which differs from what I obtain without the second query on the date which is `2023-12-15T00:00:00.000+00:00`. Is this the problem? In the query I also tried to append to `date.toIso8601String()` the `+00:00` but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Flutter does `toIso8601String()` a little weird in that the timezone stays in the local timezone. Best practice when working with a remote server is to send data to the server in UTC timezone. So, instead of:

```dart
date.toIso8601String()
```

do

```dart
date.toUtc().toIso8601String()
```

when you create the document or query.

Also, be careful with doing an exact match (`Query.equal()`) on date times because if the millisecond doesn't match up, the query won't match.